# get rid of whitespace after postheadhook thmtools

Tags: spacing, mdframed, thmtools

I want to get rid of the stupid white space after the `postheadhook` `\newline`
(see before *asdasd*)

in the following example:

```
    %!TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode


% DEFINITIONS ===================================================
\documentclass[
    12pt,
    a4paper,
    twoside,
    headings=normal,
    titlepage=true
]{scrreprt}


\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\newlength{\spacingtheorem}
\setlength{\spacingtheorem}{2mm}
\declaretheoremstyle[%
        headfont=\bfseries,%
        notebraces={(}{)},%
        bodyfont=\normalfont,%
        notefont=\itshape,%
        headpunct={:},%
        postheadspace=0mm,%
        postheadhook={\hspace{0mm}\newline},%{\textcolor{red}{\rule[.6ex]{\linewidth}{0.4pt}}\\},%
        spacebelow=0mm,%
        spaceabove=0mm,%
        mdframed={%
          frametitlealignment=\raggedright,%
          linecolor=black,%
          middlelinewidth=1pt,%
          innertopmargin=0.5\baselineskip,%
          innerbottommargin=0.5\baselineskip,%
          innerleftmargin=10pt,%
          innerrightmargin=10pt,%
          skipbelow=\dimexpr-\parskip+\spacingtheorem\relax,%
          skipabove=\spacingtheorem,%
          font=\upshape%
        }%
]{myFramedTheoremStyle}%

\declaretheorem[
    style=myFramedTheoremStyle,
    name=Theorem,
    numberwithin=chapter
]{theorem1}

\declaretheorem[
    style=myFramedTheoremStyle,
    name=Definition,
    numberwithin=chapter
]{example1}

% Basic Command
\ExplSyntaxOn
    \NewDocumentEnvironment{example} { o o }
     {%
      \IfNoValueTF{#1} {\begin{example1}}{ \begin{example1}[#1] }%                                 
      \IfNoValueTF{#2} {}{\label{#2}}%
     }%
     {%
      \end{example1}%
     }%
\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin{document}
\raggedbottom

\setlength{\parskip}{0mm}
\setlength{\parsep}{0mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{example}[asd][asd]
asdasd
\end{example}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

**How can I achieve this?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is cause by the insertion of a `\label`. I've added `\ignorespaces` after the insertion, which seems to remove the spurious spacing:

[image]

```
\documentclass[
  12pt,
  a4paper,
  twoside,
  headings=normal,
  titlepage=true
]{scrreprt}


\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\newlength{\spacingtheorem}
\setlength{\spacingtheorem}{2mm}
\declaretheoremstyle[%
  headfont=\bfseries,%
  notebraces={(}{)},%
  bodyfont=\normalfont,%
  notefont=\itshape,%
  headpunct={:},%
  postheadspace=0mm,%
  postheadhook={\hspace{0mm}\newline},%{\textcolor{red}{\rule[.6ex]{\linewidth}{0.4pt}}\\},%
  spacebelow=0mm,%
  spaceabove=0mm,%
  mdframed={%
    frametitlealignment=\raggedright,%
    linecolor=black,%
    middlelinewidth=1pt,%
    innertopmargin=0.5\baselineskip,%
    innerbottommargin=0.5\baselineskip,%
    innerleftmargin=10pt,%
    innerrightmargin=10pt,%
    skipbelow=\dimexpr-\parskip+\spacingtheorem\relax,%
    skipabove=\spacingtheorem,%
    font=\upshape%
  }%
]{myFramedTheoremStyle}%

\declaretheorem[
  style=myFramedTheoremStyle,
  name=Theorem,
  numberwithin=chapter
]{theorem1}

\declaretheorem[
  style=myFramedTheoremStyle,
  name=Definition,
  numberwithin=chapter
]{example1}

% Basic Command
\NewDocumentEnvironment{example} { o o }
  {%
   \IfNoValueTF{#1} {\begin{example1}}{ \begin{example1}[#1] }%                                 
   \IfNoValueTF{#2} {}{\label{#2}\ignorespaces}%
  }%
  {%
   \end{example1}%
  }%



\begin{document}
\raggedbottom

\setlength{\parskip}{0mm}
\setlength{\parsep}{0mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{example}[asd][asd]
asdasd
\end{example}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you want so narrow space before and after the frame. The `postfoothook` key can help, though. Vertical space after `mdframed` is often quite bizarre.

Surely, defining `example` with two optional arguments in order to avoid a spurious space if `\label` is issued is wrong.

Maybe it's not clear from the documentation of `thmtools`, but `postheadspace` can receive the value `\newline`, because it's really an interface to the spacing parameter of `amsthm` which accepts it (see its definition of the `break` theorem style).

The parentheses around the environment's name should be upright, so I used `\textup(` and `\textup)` in the definition.

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,
    a4paper,
    twoside,
    headings=normal,
    titlepage=true
]{scrreprt}


\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\newlength{\spacingtheorem}
\setlength{\spacingtheorem}{2mm}
\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont=\bfseries,
  notebraces={\textup(}{\textup)},
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
  notefont=\itshape,
  headpunct={:},
  postheadspace=\newline,
  spacebelow=0mm,
  spaceabove=0mm,
  postfoothook=\vspace{-.7\baselineskip},
  mdframed={
    frametitlealignment=\raggedright,
    linecolor=black,
    middlelinewidth=1pt,
    innertopmargin=0.5\baselineskip,
    innerbottommargin=0.5\baselineskip,
    innerleftmargin=10pt,
    innerrightmargin=10pt,
    skipbelow=\dimexpr-\parskip+\spacingtheorem\relax,
    skipabove=\spacingtheorem,
  },
]{myFramedTheoremStyle}

\declaretheorem[
    style=myFramedTheoremStyle,
    name=Theorem,
    numberwithin=chapter
]{theorem1}

\declaretheorem[
    style=myFramedTheoremStyle,
    name=Definition,
    numberwithin=chapter
]{example}

\begin{document}
\raggedbottom

\lipsum[1]
\begin{example}[asd]\label{asd}
asdasd
\end{example}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]